# traffic manager for https azure website

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

I read quite a lot documents and other questions on stackoverflow about this, and I have to admit that it just makes me much more confused.

I have a site that hosted both in EU west and EU north azure. Say their urls are:

exampleeuw.azurewebsites.net

exampleeun.azurewebsites.net

Then I bought a ssl certificate for www.example.com.

On both sites, I added www.example.com to custom domain.
On both sites, I uploaded the certificate.

Then created the traffic manager site and its dns name is "example.trafficmanager.net", I have both web app added as end point.

But should I access https://www.example.com or https://example.trafficmanager.net?

If I access https://www.example.com, how can that traffic go to the traffic manager first?

Also when I created Traffic Manager profile, I have to select a Resource group location (north Europe for example), if North Europe azure is down, will it impact the access?

Really hope that I can find some step by step examples on how Microsoft wants us to use this, as it has been a quite frustrating learning process.

Answer (score 0):

Requests should go to the traffic manager. It will be the one redirecting to both of your App Services no matter where they are.

Prior configuring your Traffic Manager and DNS, make sure both of your web application are working and configured with custom domains and SSL certificates.

Then, in your DNS, point your www.example.com website to the traffic manager as shown here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/traffic-manager-point-internet-domain/

That's all you have to do.